# On prime factors with $n^2+n+1$

Tags: number-theory

> Show that: There are infinitely many positive integers $n$  such that all prime divisors of $n^2+n+1$ are not  greater than $c\cdot n^{0.8}$, where $c$ is constant.

Maybe this $0.8$ is not best constant?  can you find the smaller number?  This is (Peking University mathematics competition)

Comment: "all divisors not greater than $x$" is confusing. Do you mean $\forall d. d\mid n^2+n+1 \implies \lnot d\gt x$, or $\lnot\forall d. k\mid n^2+n+1 \implies c\gt x$, or something else?

Comment: such $d_{i}|n^2+n+1$, then $d_{i}\le cn^{0.8}, \forall i\in N^{+}$

Comment: Since $n^2+n+1=\Phi_3(n)$, every prime factor of a number of the form $n^2+n+1$ is either $3$ or a prime of the form $3k+1$. Now we just have to derive a contradiction from the assumption that for every $n$ big enough, $n^2+n+1$ has a prime divisor $\gg n^{0.8}$. Not an easy task, at least at first sight.

Comment: According to this paper http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/PVFLPF.pdf there is an earlier result of Schinzel that for any $\alpha > 0$, there are infinitely many values of $n^2+n+1$ with all prime divisors $\le n^\alpha$ (referring to [14] Theorem 13 on p.112, with $a=1, b=-1, g=3$).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ah, the central idea seems to be to take $n = m^r$ for $r$ with many small prime factors.  Then $n^3 - 1 = m^{3r}-1 = \prod_{d\mid 3r} \Phi_d(m)$, and choosing $r$ appropriately one can make $\Phi_d(m) \ll_d m^{\phi(d)}$ small compared to $m^r$.  So yes, one can take $0.8$ to be arbitrarily small.

Comment: @ErickWong: very nice, you should put it as an answer.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Done :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact one can take $0.8$ arbitrarily small!  Let $\alpha>0$.  Then since $\prod_{p\text{ prime}} \big(1-\tfrac1p\big) \to 0$ one can choose an integer $r$ composed of many small primes such that $\tfrac{\phi(r)}{r} \le \tfrac\alpha2$, and thus $\phi(3r) \le 2\phi(r) \le \alpha r$.

If we choose $n = m^r$ for some $m > 1$, then $n^3 - 1 = m^{3r}-1$ factors into the product of cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_d(m)$ for each $d$ dividing $3r$.  Each polynomial $\Phi_d$ has degree $\phi(d)$ which divides $\phi(3r) \le \alpha r$, so each factor $\Phi_d(m)$ has size at most $C m^{\alpha r}$, where $C$ depends on the coefficients of all the cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_d$.  Thus any prime factor of $n^3-1 = (n^2+n+1)(n-1)$ can be no larger than $Cm^{\alpha r} = Cn^\alpha$.

For $\alpha = 0.8$ we can simply choose $r = 10$ so that $\phi(3r) = 8 = \alpha r$.  Looking at the cyclotomic polynomials up to $30$ shows we may comfortably take $C=5$ (in general we may use $C = 1+o(1)$ by taking $m$ large enough, since $\Phi_d$ is monic).

Comment: Thank you,It's nice, +1but this problem is middle school exam problem,maybe have other simple methods?

Comment: @abandon At the core the method is elementary: $$m^{20}+m^{10}+1 = (m^4+m^2+1)(m^8-m^7+m^5-m^4+m^3-m+1)(m^8+m^7-m^5-m^4-m^3+m+1).$$  If a middle schooler can take polynomial gcds, then it might be just about fair game, at least in a highly competitive exam.

Comment: @abandon Please clarify your question.  You never mentioned it was a middle-school exam, and you seemed more interested in finding the best possible constant.